# Not Printing On Click of Buffered Image

Tags: java

I've recently written up a script that will let me check if an Buffered-image has been clicked, but what I have, seems to no be working, I am wondering if I have done anything wrong in the process of making it, It doesn't print the "Clicked On Button" line, doesn't show anything in console about it either.

```
frame.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Point clicked = e.getPoint();
            BufferedImage bounds = Icon.guiIcons[0];
            if (((Shape) bounds).contains(clicked)) {
               System.out.println("Clicked on Inventory Button");
            }else{
                invIsOpen = false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is not working doesn't help. Is there any stack trace you could show us?

Comment: So I shoved this into a Java project, and I got this  `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.awt.image.BufferedImage cannot be cast to java.awt.Shape`  - that's probably your problem.

Comment: How can I resolve this issue>